# SQL Server 2012 error handling in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Ins2(@id   INT,@name NVARCHAR(50)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN try 
          INSERT INTO abc (id, name) 
          VALUES (@id, @name) 
      END try 

      BEGIN catch 
          INSERT INTO exception 
          VALUES (Error_number(), 
                  Error_severity(), 
                  Error_state(), 
                  Error_procedure(), 
                  Error_line(), 
                  Error_message(), 
                  Getdate()) 

          SELECT * 
          FROM   exception 
      END catch 
  END
```

**ERROR:**

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure ins2, Line 19
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

In above stored procedure `id` is the primary key in the `abc` table.. while running this I want to insert the error details in the error table (exception).. but I am getting the above error..

Comment: Post your table schema of exception table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the lenght of the data you are interting into the table . @nume param is 50 chars long ( as it's nvarchar(50) ) and the name from the abc table is maybe? not set to nvarchar(50) or bigger or is in a different format.

If you can't modify the structure of the table I suggest you trim the Parameter.

Go to your abc table select it and click ALT+F1, look at the column name and check if it's varchar or nvarchar and it lenght.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Ins2(@id   INT,@name NVARCHAR(50)) 
AS 
Declare @sName nvarchar( <insert the lenght of the column name from table abc> )
    set @sName = (SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name),0,49)
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN try 
          INSERT INTO abc (id, name) 
          VALUES (@id, @sName ) 
      END try 

      BEGIN catch 
          INSERT INTO exception 
          VALUES (Error_number(), 
                  Error_severity(), 
                  Error_state(), 
                  Error_procedure(), 
                  Error_line(), 
                  Error_message(), 
                  Getdate()) 

          SELECT * 
          FROM   exception 
      END catch 
  END 

`Declare @sName nvarchar( <insert the lenght of the column name from table abc> )` <--- this declare an variable with the lenght equal to the one from the table abc
    `set @sName = (SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name),0,49)` <-- select the first 50 chars from the parameter
```

LTRIM(RTRIM(@name) <-- always use this if you don't want any black spaces on either sides of the string

Also there is the posibility to output an error if the paramter lenght is to much for the field name in table abc.

Answer (score 2):

Error is just due to fields length. Data being inserted contain length more than field length.
Check length of fields in both "abc" and "exception" table.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect an error occurs in your catch block.
Could you confirm that length of all char columns is big enough to hold data you're trying to insert into exception table?
For example the column that should store error message might be smaller in size than error message is.
You might set it to VARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: i made changes in data type..i got the output.